# error deleting content that matches the result of a Select in ODBC

Tags: sql, odbc, delete-row

I am working with an ODBC driver, and I am trying to delete some old comments from a database. I am getting this error and I don't know why. All those tables exist and are accessible by me.

```
DELETE FROM [Z_TEST_pnt.pnt_comment_record] 
WHERE [Z_TEST_pnt.pnt_comment_record].[L2Key] IN 
   (SELECT POINT.QueueKey FROM [Z_TEST_pnt.pnt_header_record] AS POINT 
    WHERE (datediff(day, POINT.last_update_time, NOW()) > 7))
```

I get the error:

[ODBC EOP driver][OpenAccess SDK SQL Engine]Base table:Z_TEST_pnt.pnt_header_record not found.[10129]

I appreciate any suggestions. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Found it! I just needed to remove the brackets from the table names. I added them in the first place because I was having an error running that query from VBS, and I thought that the error was that I couldn't have a name with more than one dot on it.
This code works:

```
DELETE FROM Z_TEST_pnt.pnt_comment_record 
WHERE Z_TEST_pnt.pnt_comment_record.[L2Key] IN 
  (SELECT POINT.QueueKey 
   FROM Z_TEST_pnt.pnt_header_record AS POINT 
   WHERE (datediff(day, POINT.last_update_time, NOW()) > 7))
```